# Python3, flake8 - File type annotation

Tags: python, python-3.x, flake8

Trying to annotate a file in my function there is the following issue with my pep8-checker (flake8):

def my_function(myfile: file):
       pass

gives

'undefined name `file`' .

Fair enough - there is no such function in python3 anymore.
The only possibility to check for variable is a file-like object is `IOBase` from io package.

In my case it would mean that I would need to import IOBase from io package just to get a proper annotation.

```
from io import IOBase
def my_function(myfile: IOBase):
   pass
```

Is there another way to proper anotate an argument of file-type properly?

Answer (score 0):

You are using or running the wrong version of flake. The code above works perfectly with `flake8-2.5.0`